# VS Code - How to Hide Files' Paths in Search Palette

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

When I search for some keywords in my project using the Search palette, VS Code by default shows the path of each file beside the file in the search result section, as shown below (i.e., folder-one\folder-two):

[image]

How can I hide the paths? I googled and searched in the VS Code settings, but could not be successful.

Comment: before you go down the "how" path, can you share "why" you want to do that? It seems pretty logical to show folder location next to file path so you can figure out the correct path as two files with the same name can exist in different folders.

Comment: @Asdfg, since my project has a huge number of files and when I want to have just a little bit look on the search result, then these paths make it really hard to do that.

Comment: You will need to add [custom CSS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css). You can get the element selector from the Developer Tools